# Can I change the convention for string column generation by EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Using a very specific example for ultimately a more general question: How can I configure the column type convention for Code First column generation to use `nvarchar(50)` instead of `nvarchar(MAX)` for string columns?

Comment: The very specific example has a very specific answer, so what is the more general question you want to ask? If you want to be able to choose arbitrary database types, you cannot.

Comment: I'd like to know which conventions I am able to configure and how to do it.

Comment: I found this searching for exactly that specific question - in fact I wrote up my question before the search even found this - to which the answer appears to be, in simple terms, "no".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default db type two ways:

Firstly, you can add the appropriate attribute to the property. An annotation of `[StringLength(50)]` specifies a length of 50.

Secondly, you can configure the property using the `StringPropertyConfiguration` methods.

```
var entityTypeConfiguration = modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>;
entityTypeConfiguration.Property(t => t.StringProperty).HasMaxLength(50);
```

You can check the other `StringPropertyConfiguration` methods to see what other options are available for configuration.

Comment: You have told me how to specify the column type for specific properties. I am asking how to configure the **convention** so that all string properties get `nvarchar(50)` instead of `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Oh... that's why I didn't get it. No, as far as I know that is not configurable, you have to specify it for each column.

Comment: That said, what you can do is call `Type.GetProperties`, find all string properties, build a property accessor for each of them, and call `HasMaxLength` in a loop.